# How to convert std::wstring to a const TCHAR*?

Tags: c++, windows, unicode, tchar

I have the following wstring:

```
std::wstring testVal("Test");
```

Which I need to place inside this value:

```
 static const TCHAR* s_test_val;
```

So far I have tried:

```
 static const TCHAR* s_test_val = (const wchar_t*) testVal.c_str();
 static const TCHAR* s_test_val = (wchar_t*) testVal.c_str();
 static const TCHAR* s_test_val = (TCHAR*) testVal.c_str();
 static const TCHAR* s_test_val = (TCHAR*) testVal;
```

But without success; s_test_val keeps appearing as an empty string.

Comment: Back in the late 1990s Microsoft had two operating system lines, the ANSI-based Windows 9X and the Unicode-based Windows NT. In order to make it easy for programmers to write the same code for both OS lines, Microsoft hid the differences behind a series of macros that switch back and forth between ANSI characters and Unicode characters depending on compiler options, and `TCHAR` is one of those macros. Windows NT all but wiped out Windows 9X in the early 2000s with Windows XP, and probably every Windows computer you've used in the last 15 years uses Unicode.

Comment: Unless for some reason you need to support 20+ year-old Windows OSes along with the modern variety, you should either not use `TCHAR` and use wide characters and the various ...w functions throughout or make sure you have unicode specified when compiling. Though if you're just hacking something out, you might want to stick with 8-bit characters for simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

```
static const TCHAR* s_test_val = testVal.c_str();
```

This one is correct on the condition that `UNICODE` is defined in which case `TCHAR` will be an alias of `wchar_t`.

If `UNICODE` isn't defined, then you would need to perform some conversion, but it might not be worth the effort to support non-unicode builds. Your attempt that uses a cast would silently do the wrong thing in that case while this one safely produces an error.

In case you don't care about non-unicode support (and I cannot think of a reason why anyone would), then I recommend minimising the use of `TCHAR` entirely.

Comment: You can't think why anyone would care about unicode? :D

Comment: How do you define UNICODE?

Comment: @user3400351 What does the manual of your compiler say?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `TCHAR` unless Windows 9x support is essential. Additionally, your static pointer pointing to an automatic variable is very suspicious. You either want:

```
static wchar_t constexpr const*  s_test_val = L"Test";
```

or

```
std::wstring testVal = L"Test";
wchar_t const* s_test_val = testVal.c_str();
```

or

```
std::wstring testVal = L"Test";
auto const s_test_val = testVal.c_str();
```

Comment: This didn't work. I can't change anything in my variables, just find a way to convert wchar_t to UNICODE

Comment: @user3400351 it is *already* Unicode, so what are you trying to convert exactly? When `UNICODE` is defined, `TCHAR` maps to `wchar_t`